# Wordpress custom post type routing

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on the site powered by Wordpress.

I have many custom post types and have a problem with routing:

For example, I have custom post type: `tips` and I would like to know,

**How can i get to use urls like these?**

- Category:  https://example.com/tips/category-name
- Category + subcategory:  https://example.com/tips/category-name/subcategory-name
- Article: https://example.com/tips/article-title

Thanks in advance